# How do I generate .d.ts typings from Flow code?

Tags: flowtype

I have enabled Flow on a JavaScript project I am developing.  Since I am putting in the effort to providing type annotations, I would really like to generate ***.d.ts** files so the broader TypeScript community can also have type information.

How can I generate ***.d.ts** type definition files from Flow-annotated JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good automated way to do it at the moment. I've seen some attempts at it, but when I run those tools they typically output minimally useful/useless definitions. If it were me, I'd manually write (minimal) TypeScript annotations and see if anyone else bothers to expand upon them.

Comment: This question is old but still relevant. Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I searched for the available tools. I found the following.

The first one is the most up to date one. It can convert the whole Flow code to TypeScript. I have used it personally, and it works like a charm.

https://github.com/Khan/flow-to-ts

Other ones:

https://github.com/Kiikurage/babel-plugin-flow-to-typescript

https://github.com/burnnat/flow-to-dts

https://github.com/bcherny/flow-to-typescript

https://github.com/yuya-takeyama/flow2dts